# NHibernate mapping for a readonly property using iterators (yield return)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to map a readonly property in NHibernate that uses an iterator (i.e., yield return)?

For example, lets say we had a `Person` class with a read-only `IEnumerable<Cat> Cats` property and a method called `GetNextCat()` that gets the next cat in a sequence.

Here is the possible mapping:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Cats).Access.ReadOnly(); // also tried .AsSet() and .AsBag()
    }
}
```

And here are two possible implementations of the `IEnumerable<Cat> Cats` property:

```
// fails: 
//   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<get_Cats>d__0' to 
//   type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[MyProject.Cat]'.
public virtual IEnumerable<Cat> Cats
{
    get
    {
        var cat = GetNextCat();

        while(cat != null)
        {
            yield return cat;
            cat = GetNextCat();
        }

        yield break;
    }
}

// works
public virtual IEnumerable<Cat> Cats
{
    get
    {
        var catList = new List<Cat>();
        var cat = GetNextCat();

        while(cat != null)
        {
            catList.Add(cat);
            cat = GetNextCat();
        }

        return catList;
    }
}
```

Both versions of the property produce the same results. Why, then, does NHibernate break with the first example, yet works with the second? Is it that NHibernate just isn't set up to deal with the compiler-generated classes from `yield return`? Or is this just an issue with Fluent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the properties is distinct.

The first produces an generated IEnumerable (iterator) the secod returns a generated list. NHibernate tries to wrap a ICollection/ISet/Ilist (depending on AsBag/Set/List) in a persistentBag/Set/List which fails for IEnumerable and succeeds for List.

However both are incorrect in that NHibernate can not change track on the fly generated objects so the second code will run but yield crazy results and or exceptions down the road.

**Conclusion:** do not map this property at all because it is generated in code and not loaded from database. Load/Map the persistent data `GetNextCat()` uses to get the next cat.

Comment: Interesting. In that case, would you recommend avoiding mapping any property as read only, or just when the property is some kind of collection (or complex object)?

Comment: readonly has its uses, but you have a totally different problem. You have a generated property like `public double Cost { get { return Price * Cost; } }` and no readonly property `public double Cost { get { return _cost; } }`